# Error al guardar un dato en una tabla de MySQL desde un formulario .NET con C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Hola a toda la comunidad.
Seré muy puntual. Tengo un problema a la hora de ingresar datos a la base de datos mysql desde c#.net, la conexión aparenta estar bien, de hecho, el dato ingresa, pero, cuando reviso la base de datos me aparece algo diferente **"mysql.class_color"**. a continuación anexo las imágenes

---

tengo una **clase conexión,** esta contiene el string de conexión

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace mysql
{
    //CLASE para conectar con base de datos
    public class Class_conexion
    {
        //METODO -> ObtenerConexion() <- que genera un objeto para conectar a la base de datos
        public static MySqlConnection ObtenerConexion()
        {
            MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.0; database=database; Uid=root; pwd=*******;");
            conectar.Open();
            return conectar;   
        }
    }
}
```

---

tengo una **clase color,** esta representa la tabla en la DB

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace mysql
{
    class Class_Color
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }

        public Class_Color() {}

        public Class_Color(string pColor)
        {
            this.Color = pColor;
        }
    }
}
```

---

tengo la **clase crud,** que me permite agregar datos a la tabla

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace mysql
{
    class Class_CRUD
    {
        public static int Agregar(Class_Color pColor)
        {
            int retorno = 0;
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("insert into color(color) values('{0}')", pColor), Class_conexion.ObtenerConexion());
            retorno = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return retorno;
        }
    }
}
```

---

por ultimo, tengo mi archivo principal, desde donde instancio las clases cuando presiono el botón Guardar

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace mysql
{
    public partial class EntradaDatos : Form
    {
        public EntradaDatos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class_Color pColor = new Class_Color();
            pColor.Color = textBox_color.Text.Trim();
            int resultado = Class_CRUD.Agregar(pColor);

            if(resultado > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("color guardado con exito, eres un campeon!!!");
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo guardar el color", "PERDEDOR!, cambie de carrera", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

el problema es: No se agrega el texto que escribo en cambio se esta agregando **mysql.class_color**

```
+-------------------+
| color             |
+-------------------+
| mysql.Class_Color |
+-------------------+
```

**Que estoy haciendo mal??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma en que estas asignando el valor recupera el `ToString()` de la clase en lugar del valor de la propiedad

```
string.Format("insert into... VALUES ({0})", pcolor.Color);
```

tienes que pones la propiedad como value del insert

Salvo que redefinas el `ToString()`, pudes hacerlo en un simple ejemplo

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Class_Color pColor = new Class_Color();
        pColor.Color = "Azul";

        Console.WriteLine(pColor); 
    }   
}


public class Class_Color
{
    public string Color {get;set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Color;
    }
}
```

quita el `override` del `ToString()` y veras que devuelve el nombre de la clase

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, sin embargo sigo sin entender, yo no e colocado 'override' en ninguna parte, a que se refiere con eso, por otro lado la reduccion que hiso del codigo no logro contextulizarla del todo con el mio, por ejemplo: se supone que `Class_Color pColor = new Class_Color();
        pColor.Color = textBox.text` debe darme el valor del texto que escribi en el text box

Comment: justamente porque no agregaste el override del ToString() es que no obtienes el valor de la propiedad Color, me pregunto sabes lo que es una propiedad? si es asi tienes que usarlo en el string.Foramt() qu asigna el valor del valor en el insert

Comment: Wow! viejo @LeandroTuttini, gracias ya funciono!, modifique la clase color agregando el `override` como lo sugieres y funciona perfecto! también quedé con la frustración de no entender muy bien como funciona, pero ya mismo buscare de que se tratan lo de las propiedades, no tengo ni idea de eso.

Comment: pero en la clase ya la defines en `Color` cuando usas el get y set, eso es una propiedad, defines algo que no sabes de que se trata?

Comment: el metodo de la clase color estaba asi: `public Class_Color (string pColor){this.Color = pColor;}` lo que hice entonces fue `public override string ToString(){return this.Color = Color;}` yo había definido anteriormente como creía que funcionaba y la verdad confieso "_aunque debe ser chocante y debo parece un tonto a los posibles lectores leer esto que no comprendo muy bien como funciona, pero funciona_." Ya mismo me pondré a investigar sobre esto. La verdad soy un novato en esto de la programación.